# Hide a specific DIV element that has been dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

The field `Description` is optional and only appears when the user clicks on the `+ Description` button. However when another div is generated the code loses the focus of the element it should hide and the button doesn't work anymore.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $(document).on('click', '#hide-desc', function(e) {
            $("#description").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a button to remove and add the following div:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
        <!-- Among other stuff -->
        <div id="description" class="item-child-desc">
            {{ form }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-action-button">
        <!-- Deletes item-wrapper and another button adds it -->
        <a id="delete" href="#" class="button alt small special">Remove</a>
        <a id="hide-desc" class="button alt small">+ Description</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the function must be able to identify which `description` I am talking about, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to get the parent div of the button and specify the div with method `find()` but I could not make it work.

I have the same problem happening with an autocomplete function. I believe I will get both working if I can figure out what I have to do.

Comment: Just moment - you create multple #description divs, or i didn't understand your question?

Comment: Yes, I create multiple descriptions within parent divs "item-wrapper".

Comment: Give them class - id must be unique.

Comment: Ok, but how will the script know which "#description" it should hidden if there could be multiple instances created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I assume your html sort of looks like this (note that we use `.description` rather than `#description` since those are not unique elements):

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="item-action-button">
        <a id="delete" href="#" class="button alt small special">Remove</a>
        <a id="hide-desc" class="button alt small">+ Description</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description" class="item-child-desc">
        blergh
    </div>
</div>
```

We just have to look for the parent `.item-wrapper` using `e.target` to reference the source of the event then search the child `.description`:

```
$(e.target).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".description").slideToggle();
```

Based on the sample html you've added, the following should also work without modification:

```
$(e.target).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle();
```

It's also possible to just use `this`:

```
$(this).parents(".item-wrapper").find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle();
```

In all cases, the crucial part is `parents(".item-wrapper")`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was using $(this).parent().find(".description").slideToggle(); I was hopping that it would find the parent of the button (this) and look for "description". But it worked really week. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *entirely* certain of the question, but if my understanding is correct I believe I may have found a solution for you. Using jQuery [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), it's relatively simple!

Run this code snippet and see if I'm close to a solution:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-action-button"> <a href="#" class="delete button alt small special">Remove</a>
 <a class="hide-desc button alt small">+ Description</a>
    <div class="item-child-desc">{{ form }}</div>
</div>

<div class="item-action-button"> <a href="#" class="delete button alt small special">Remove</a>
 <a class="hide-desc button alt small">+ Description</a>
</div>

<div class="item-action-button"> <a href="#" class="delete button alt small special">Remove</a>
 <a class="hide-desc button alt small">+ Description</a>
    <div class="item-child-desc">{{ form }}</div>
</div>

<div class="item-action-button"> <a href="#" class="delete button alt small special">Remove</a>
 <a class="hide-desc button alt small">+ Description</a>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".item-action-button").on('click', '.hide-desc', function (e) {
        $(e.delegateTarget).find(".item-child-desc").slideToggle();
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  .item-child-desc {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

The problem with using ids for event handling is that they are only ever registered with the *last element with that matching id*. If you want one event handler for all elements of a certain type, register an event handler with elements of a certain *class* or *tag*. You'd be doing yourself a disservice otherwise.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. But I dont know if it is only here, but the snippet did not work.

Comment: OK, I understood what was going wrong now. Id was a bad choice. Thanks!